# Update last fetched Id from select query while using JDBC inbound channel adapter in Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am using JDBC Ibound channel adaptor - Trying to update a column in a table whose Value will be the value of column of the the last record fetched in the select query

Tried using payload[key] and :column_value_of_lastselectedrecord

```
`<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="pollTradeDataChannelAdapter"
        channel="pollTradeDataChannel" data-source="datasource" 
        query="select id, name from employee"
        update="update cache set id = :payload[id]">
        <int:poller id="pollTradeDataChannelAdapterPoller" error-channel="pollTradeServiceErrorChannel" 
            fixed-delay="5000">
            <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionmanager" />
        </int:poller>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`
```

While trying to run my application using the above spring integration configuration it's throwing SQL exception SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type. Please assist on how to get the data updated on back of the select query fired.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your *update a column in a table whose Value will be the value of column of the the last record fetched* you need to have a custom expression configured for the parameter.

you need to inject via `update-sql-parameter-source-factory` attribute a customized `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` with a configured `setParameterExpressions`. I thinks a SpEL expression like this should work for you:

```
sqlParameterSourceFactory.setParameterExpressions(Collections.singletonMap("lastId", "#root.$[true].id"))
```

The `update` query must be like this then: `update="update cache set id = :lastId"`.

There is no `payload` context for update query in the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

**UPDATE**

OK. I did some debugging and figured out that `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` doesn't fit to your requirements. Whenever an `input` is a `Collection`, the provided expression is wrapped to another one and we can't impact its result any way.

For your `last item selection` use-case I've invented something like this:

```
public class MySqlParameterSourceFactory implements SqlParameterSourceFactory {

    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        return new MySqlParameterSource(input);
    }

    private static class MySqlParameterSource implements SqlParameterSource {

        private final Map<String, Object> lastResult;

        public MySqlParameterSource(Object input) {
            this.lastResult = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) input).stream()
                    .reduce((first, second) -> second)
                    .orElse(null);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasValue(String paramName) {
            return lastResult.containsKey(paramName);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue(String paramName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            return lastResult.get(paramName);
        }

    }

}
```

So, whenever your select returns a list of items, you always select only the last one from there and a parameter value resolution is done against a map for the last item.

The channel adapter configuration would be them like this:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="pollTradeDataChannelAdapter"
    channel="pollTradeDataChannel" data-source="datasource" 
    query="select id, name from employee"
    update-sql-parameter-source-factory="sqlParameterSourceFactory"
    update="update cache set id = :id">
    <int:poller id="pollTradeDataChannelAdapterPoller" error-channel="pollTradeServiceErrorChannel" 
        fixed-delay="5000">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionmanager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<beans:bean id="sqlParameterSourceFactory"
            class="my.com.my.project.MySqlParameterSourceFactory"/>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still getting the same SQL exception - Invalid column type
`<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="tica" 
        query="select id, name from employee"
        update="update cache set id = :lastid" 
        update-sql-parameter-source-factory="updateSource">
        <int:poller id="tpoll" fixed-delay="5000">
            <int:transactional transaction-manager="tm" />
        </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: `<bean id="updateSource" class =ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
      <property name="parameterExpressions">
         <map>
     <entry key="lastid" value="#root.$[0].id"/>
        </map>
     </property>
 </bean>
`

I had tried using #root.$[true].id as you had suggested but it didn't work and threw SQL exception ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification as there were multiple ids fetched from select query. So I thought of using #root.$[0].id to fetch the first id selected but it didn't work either. Please assist.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Indeed `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` doesn't work for you. Sorry for confusing.